# Error in DataGridview.CellContentClick

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am handling cell content click event.
When user clicks the content of a cell it captures accurately.

Consider the case, where I have DataGridViewLinkColumn at column 3
But after clicking a cell ( say row 1 column 3), when the user accidently clicks at any of the table Header,cellclick event is retained i.e. it calls CellContentClicked event with same RowIndex and ColumnIndex(row 1 and column 3).

How to avoid this?
Pls help..

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question.
I am working in Winforms 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer..
On clicking the table header, cell click is fired for previous selected cell.

We can limit this functionality by adding the condition,

```
if (e.CoumnIndex >= 0 && e.RowIndex >= 0)
{

  // Add  Logic neccessary for Cell Click event
}
```

(As rowIndex is -1 for Header row)

Answer (score 0):

Well this basically happens because of last/default selected row. To get around this problem, you can either define your control with default selection property set to none.

Like in case of a listview, I am using this :

```
<ListView ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource listViewStyle}" SelectedIndex=-1 .. />
```

Comment: @StanislavStoyanov, I am unsure if he is working in wpf, asp.net or Win-forms. BTW, Is it different when working in windows forms development ?

Answer (score 0):

For Windows Form Applications,

```
if (e.ColumnIndex >= 0 && e.RowIndex >= 0)
{         
    // Add  Logic  for Cell Click event
}
else
{
   MessageBox.Show("Error Message", "My Application",
   MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
}
```